# jquery selecting closest div

Tags: jquery

Categories div is hidden and i want it to be shown when toggler is hovered. Any help would be appreciated.

html

```
<div class="categorization">
 <a href="#" class="toggler">something</a>

 <div class="categories">
 </div>

</div>
```

i tried this.

jquery

```
  $(".categorization .toggler").hover(function() {
   $(this).closest('.categories').show();
  }, function(){
   $(this).closest('.categories').hide();
  });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) walks the ancestor tree, so it's not what you're looking for. You can use [nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) and [first()](http://api.jquery.com/first/) to achieve what you want:

```
$(".categorization .toggler").hover(function() {
    $(this).nextAll(".categories").first().show();
}, function(){
    $(this).nextAll(".categories").first().hide();
});
```

Note that [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) only matches the very next element, so `next(".categories")` will only work if the `<div>` element immediately follows your toggler element.

Answer (score 3):

```
var categoryDiv = $(this).next('div'); // or
var categoryDiv = $(this).next('.categories');
```

this will get you the next div sibling relative to toggler.

Answer (score 0):

Note that :

In jquery API,

.closest() : Get the first ancestor element that matches the selector, beginning at the current element and progressing up through the DOM tree.

Apparently, your <div> element is not an ancestor element of <a>

see http://api.jquery.com/closest/

In this case, you should try .next(), if you want to get only one element,
or .nextAll(), if you want to get all elements matches your selector.